# Importing generated excel file to google sheets is changing its fonts

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, google-sheets, xlsxwriter

Apologies in advance, I am very new to python. I generated an excel file using xlsxwriter lib. I explicitly set the font Calibri for all the texts that are printed in the file.
The code that I used for setting my font is given below

```
GLOBAL_FONT_NAME = 'Calibri'


def set_font(cell_format):
    cell_format.set_font(GLOBAL_FONT_NAME)
    cell_format.set_font_family(0)
    return cell_format
```

The way I wrote data into the cells is given below

```
worksheet.write('F2', 'Total Emp', cell_format)
```

I used all my cell formats in this way. This works in LibreOffice and Microsoft Excel. But if I import the generated file in google sheets, it shows the font as Arial. Why is this happening? Any ideas on how I can fix this?

Comment: If you try making an Excel file manually (i.e. using Excel), setting the font to Calibri, and uploading to Google Sheets, the result is the same (at least it was for me). It therefore seems Google Sheets does not attempt to match the spreadsheet's font when importing.

Comment: Ok is there any way to force google sheets to use a specific font for a given file?